# redux: combine reducers with asymmetric reducer structure?

Tags: reactjs, redux

I am a little confused if I can use `combineReducers` in my situation...

my state:

```
settings = {
    A: {
        settingA: {...objects},
        settingB: 'foo',
        settingC: 'bar',
    },

    AReused: {
        settingA: {...objects},
        settingB: 'like_A',
        settingC: 'but_not_A',
    },

    B: {
        settingA: 'setting',
        settingB: 'foo',
        settingC: 'bar',
    }

    isFetching: false,
    someOtherSetting: 'wooohoo'
}
```

I have a few questions about reducers with a state like this...

1. `A` and `AReused` can use the same reducer, but if I do something like...

   `const reducer = combinReducers({
       A: AReducer,
       AReused: AReducer,
   })`

   then how is redux going to differentiate between the actions coming in? and dispatch them to change `A` or `AReused` accordingly?
2. Because I will need to fetch this at sometime, how can I handle a reducer that is one step above the reducers and can toggle `isFetching` as well as dispatch an action that will give a whole new state once it is fetched?

Comment: All actions are dispatched to all the reducers in redux, you need to catch the approriate action and modify your state accordingly and for actions that don't need to modify the state for a particular reducer you return a default state

Comment: I think you should read further the documentation of redux. You have misunderstood some of base principles of redux, like the one pointed by Shubham Khatri